# Linux Hostname - SystemD Service File Causing NetworkManager to Fail on Boot

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

`systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Job nis-domainname.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with NetworkManager-wait-online.service/start`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While awaiting a fix, you can remove `After=network-online.target` from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nis-domainname.service`